# show/hide a widget without recreating it

Tags: flutter

Let's say I have 2 cards and one is shown on screen at a time. I have a button that replaces the current card with other cards. Now assume that there is some data on card 1 and some data on card 2 and I don't want to destroy the data on each of them or I don't want to rebuild any of them again.

I tried using Stack Widget and overlapping one on top of others with a boolean on the top card. The value of this boolean is reversed by calling `setstate` when the button is pressed. The issue is as soon as I press the button, the new card rebuilds all over again and then shown or `initState` is called again, which I don't want. Any Solution?

EDIT: Sample Code:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(new MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: new ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: new MyHomePage(title: 'Flutter Demo Home Page'),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  MyHomePage({Key key, this.title}) : super(key: key);
  final String title;

  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => new _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  var toggleFlag = false;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new Scaffold(
      appBar: new AppBar(
        title: new Text(widget.title),
      ),
      body: new Center(
        child: toggleFlag
            ? CustomWidget(color: Colors.blue)
            : CustomWidget(color: Colors.red),
      ),
      floatingActionButton: new FloatingActionButton(
        onPressed: _toggleCard,
        tooltip: 'Increment',
        child: new Icon(Icons.add),
      ), // This trailing comma makes auto-formatting nicer for build methods.
    );
  }

  void _toggleCard() {
    setState(() {
      toggleFlag = !toggleFlag;
    });
  }
}

class CustomWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  var color;

  CustomWidget({this.color});

  @override
  State<StatefulWidget> createState() {
    return new MyState();
  }
}

class MyState extends State<CustomWidget> {
  @override   //I don't want this to be called again and again
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {  
    return new Container(
      height: 100.0,  
      width: 100.0,
      color: widget.color,
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you show a bit of code?

Comment: @RémiRousselet Added a sample code

Comment: The fact that build method is called again is normal. What is not normal is the initState. Can you show an example where your initState get called. Again?

Answer (score 8):

1-Solution:
You have an array of widgets like this

```
  final widgetList[widget1(), widget2()]
  int currentIndex = 0;

  IndexedStack (
    index: currentIndex,
    children: widgetList,
   ));
```

2-Solution:

With the `Stack` widget

```
  int currentIndex = 0;

Stack(
   children: [
   Offstage(
    offstage: currentIndex != 0,
    child: bodyList[0],
   ),
   Offstage(
    offstage: currentIndex != 1,
    child: bodyList[1],
   ),
   Offstage(
    offstage: currentIndex != 2,
    child: bodyList[2],
   ),
   ],
  )
```

3-Solution:
You need to add this to your stateful widget state

```
AutomaticKeepAliveClientMixin <Widgetname> like this

   class _WidgetState extends State <Widgetname> with AutomaticKeepAliveClientMixin     <Widgetname> {
   @override
      bool get wantKeepAlive => true;
   }
```

Answer (score 1):

just wrap that Widget inside a Visibility widget then set "maintainSate" to true

```
Visibility(
        visible: toggleFlag,
        maintainState: true,
        child: const CustomWidget(),
      )
```

Comment: You are the life saviour..

Answer (score -4):

Stateless widgets are always considered to be perishable.  If you want to preserve state, use a StatefulWidget and a State subclass.

Comment: both my cards are stateful widget. The question is can we call setstate in parent widget without recreating the child widgets?